# How to delete space in character text?

Tags: date, concatenation, abap

I wrote a code that automatically pulls time-related information from the system. As indicated in the table is fixed t247 Month names to 10 characters in length. But it is a bad image when showing on the report screen.

[image]

I print this way:

```
  WRITE : 'Bugün', t_month_names-ltx, ' ayının'.
  CONCATENATE gv_words-word '''nci günü' INTO date.
  CONCATENATE date ',' INTO date.
  CONCATENATE date gv_year INTO date SEPARATED BY space.
  TRANSLATE   date TO LOWER CASE.
```

I tried the `CONDENSE t_month_names-ltx NO-GAPS.` method to delete the spaces, but it was not enough.

After WRITE, I was able to write statically by setting the blank value:

```
  WRITE : 'Bugün', t_month_names-ltx.
  WRITE : 14 'ayının'.
  CONCATENATE gv_words-word '''nci günü' INTO date.
  CONCATENATE date ',' INTO date.
  CONCATENATE date gv_year INTO date SEPARATED BY space.
  TRANSLATE   date TO LOWER CASE.
```

[image]

But this is not a correct use. How do I achieve this dynamically?

Comment: You currently get `Bugün Temmuz     ayının yirmidört'nci günü, 2020` or `Bugün Temmuz ayının yirmidört'nci günü, 2020`. What exact text do you expect please? Moreover, do you expect this text to be stored in a variable or to be output with WRITE?

Comment: CONDENSE worked for me, even without `NO-GAPS`. What is the type of `date` field? It should be string, not char

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a temporary field of type STRING:

```
DATA l_month TYPE STRING.

l_month = t_month_names-ltx.

WRITE : 'Bugün', l_month.
WRITE : 14 'ayının'.
CONCATENATE gv_words-word '''nci günü' INTO date.
CONCATENATE date ',' INTO date.
CONCATENATE date gv_year INTO date SEPARATED BY space.
TRANSLATE   date TO LOWER CASE.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not delete trailing spaces from a TYPE C field, because it's of constant length. The unused length is always filled with spaces.

But after you assembled you string, you can use `CONDENSE` without NO-GAPS to remove any chains of more than one space within the string.

Add `CONDENSE date.` below the code you wrote and you should get the results you want.

Another option is to abandon `CONCATENATE` and use [string templates](https://jorg.thuijls.net/2017/01/13/strings-and-string-templates-in-abap/) (string literals within `|` symbols) for string assembly instead, which do not have the annoying habit of including trailing spaces of TYPE C fields:

```
DATA long_char TYPE C LENGTH 128.
long_char = 'long character field'.

WRITE |this is a { long_char } inserted without spaces|.
```

Output:

```
this is a long character field inserted without spaces
```